# Why is a PNG file from a Grid completely black?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to save a PNG image of a WPF Grid to file. The Grid is shown fine on the MainWindow, but the created file is completely black (though its dimensions are fine.)

Here is the code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();    
    int length = 30;

    //Create Grid:
    Grid myGrid = new Grid
    {
        Width = length,
        Height = length,
        Background = Brushes.Aqua,
    };

    //Save to file:
    RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(length, length, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
    bmp.Render(myGrid);
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\test.png", FileMode.Create);
    encoder.Save(fileStream);

    //Show on Window: (shows fine.)
    gridOnMainWindow.Children.Add(myGrid);
}
```

Comment: What about measure/arrange?

Comment: @Mitch What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a tool like `RenderTargetBitmap`, you must involve yourself in the `Measure`/`Arrange` cycle of the WPF layout process.  See [MSDN > WPF > Advanced > Layout > Measuring and Arranging Children](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/layout#measuring-and-arranging-children).

Changing your example to:

```
int length = 30;

//Create Grid:
Grid myGrid = new Grid
{
    Width = length,
    Height = length,
    Background = Brushes.Aqua,
};
myGrid.Measure(new Size(length, length));
myGrid.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, length, length));

//Save to file:
RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap(length, length, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmp.Render(myGrid);
PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite("test.png"))
{
    encoder.Save(fileStream);
}
```

Results in the expected image:

[image: Cyan]

Comment: Thanks. Perfect. Just to make sure I understood the reason correctly. The Grid was never completely rendered before saving to file, but was shown correctly because the MainWindow (and the `gridOnMainWindow`) were calling these methods to finalize its rendering. Am I correct?

Comment: That's correct.  When you add it to the `Grid` you had in the window, the window called Measure on that grid, which in turn called Measure on your grid.  Prior to this point, the sizes and layout were all 0 - so the PNG was a rendering of a grid 0 pixels wide by 0 pixels tall.

Comment: Specifically, calling `Measure` and `Arrange` results in the `DesiredSize` and `ActualSize` properties becoming non-zero.  If you set a breakpoint before and after each step, you will see those changing.

Comment: ...Thanks again!